# Making an accumulated sum graph with QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, amazon-quicksight

How can I make an accumulated sum graph with [AWS QuickSight](https://aws.amazon.com/quicksight/)?
For example, I have a dataset that contains the sales for each day. I want to make a line graph for each month that has the **accumulated** sells day by day.

So if the dataset is:

- Day1 = 10 sales
- Day2 = 5 sales
- Day3 = 11 sales

The graph should have a line with Day 1 = 10, Day 2 = 15, Day 3 = 26, etc.

There is a function function called [runningSum()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/runningSum-function.html) in the Quicksight documentation, but how can this be used with a QuickSight Visual (graph)?

Comment: You need to use a "Calculated Field". Unfortunately I can't add an answer because this question is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to this. I did it the following way:

```
runningSum(sum({count}), [truncDate("MM",{creationdate}) ASC], [{region}])
```

and I found an interesting catch.... whenever I tried adding **at the moment that I'm configuring the data source, it'd fail**.

So I went through and **added the calculated field on the area where I can edit the visuals** - and there it worked.

Here's an example of the accumulative view:

[image: accumulative view on quicksight]

Hope it works for you.

Comment: For graphs QuickSight does not show the runningSum or runningCount fields. How did you add this? As a Parameter Calculated field? If so, how do you use that within the graphs?

Comment: Precisely, you first need to add a calculated field to you analysis - there’s a lot of functions that are exclusive to the formulas. Once you add a calculated field (I’ve provided an example of how the formula should look like) it will be available just like the other fields, you can drag it to use it as the Y axis of you graph.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [`runningSum`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/runningSum-function.html).